# Row number for Excel table reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with few tables, but on different sheets and positions. The summary table is referencing each one. The problem is that I get #VALUE! errors when using this formula:

```
=Table1[@Column1]
```

As shown on the example below it works when two tables are in the same row, but when the same table is moved away or down, it's stops working. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You should remove the `@`

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

With the following structured reference

```
=Table1[@Column1]
```

You are doing the # This Row context i.e. it will only work correctly if your additional table is aligned on the same rows.

If you line the tables up you will see it works.

**Solution:**

You can cheat as follows by referencing both tables and using the `OFFSET` and  `ROW` function:

```
=OFFSET(Table1,ROW(F9)-ROW(Table2),,1,1)
```

**Notes:**

1) `ROW(F9)-ROW(Table2)` generates the number of rows to offset by.

2) `=CELL("address",Table1)` gives you the first data body range cell address in the table.

[image: Cheat]

You can use similar idea with Index

```
=INDEX(Table1[Column1], ROWS($E$17:E17))
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but I cannot manually offset for each source table, because they are resizing and they are in different sheets. So I would just need to match row number of both tables (not sheet) I guess? Can it be done with CELL?

Comment: What do you mean? These will adjust as you move tables around and provided both tables resize at the same time then autofill will add in the required formula to the new rows. You can also work across sheets in this way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure i understood your question correctly.
This however, works no matter where the tables are placed:

```
Sub Table_Reference()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Table1[Column1]")

Range("Table2[Column1]").Value = rng.Value

End Sub
```

You might want to specify the worksheet you're working in at the beginning of the code.

**Edit:**

As VBA is unwanted by the OP i suggest using `=INDEX(Table1[Column1]; 1)`
This would reference the first row of data in the specified table and column eg. "Table1" and "Column1".
Referencing the next row would be `=INDEX(Table1[Column1]; 2)` and so on.
However you would need to type this manually into each cell that's supposed to have a reference.

Comment: This would need to work without VBA. Just a simple reference. Table 1 is the first one and the other two are referencing to it. The one in the same line works, the other doesn't.

Comment: @shafac14, if you want a solution without the use of VBA I'd suggest you remove the VBA tags from your post.

Comment: @shafac14 I agree with Luuklag. You should remove the VBA tag if you do not accept a VBA-based solution. I've updated my answer to include a sub-optimal non-VBA solution.